# Quarq Dfour Fit Problem

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket, power

I recently buy my first Quarq Dfour power meter to replace my crank Shimano Ultegra 6800. but I have the problem that the quarq spindle its too short ( 106 mm quarq vs 109 mm shimano ultra ). I don't know if I buy the correct quarq ( GXP or BB30 ) and I don't know if I need change my bottom bracket ( actually I use Kogel Press Fit BB30 to 24 ceramic.)

I want use the quarq but I don't know how fix this issue.

Do I need change my actual bottom bracket to another ? ... que quarq dfour its correct for my frame ? ( my bike is a Felt IA2 2016 ) ...

[image: https://image.ibb.co/nrgA20/IMG-2927.jpg]
[image: https://image.ibb.co/d7JON0/IMG-2928.jpg]

Comment: Can you, please, post the pictures of the non-drive side crank? **Perhaps** the one from Quark is more narrow in the spindle section than the one from Ultegra and you're ok with the whole assembly.

Comment: I have to say I'm confused by Quarq offering a product explicitly for Shimino chainrings, that does not have a Shimano 24mm spindle option.

Answer (score 3):

@Victor this can be made to work.

The new crank has a GXP interface spindle, you can notice that by a notch before NDS arm splines start, which serves as a stops against inner bearing race, and the fact that splines are on non-drive side (SRAM BB30 splines are on drive-side). Since GXP is a Truvativ/SRAM variation on 24mm spindle, it should fit everywhere Shimano 24mm Hollowtech II fits. The spindle length is no problem, BB30 bottom bracket shells are the narrowest (68mm, FC-6800 is designed around 86mm bearings stance), so with the right bottom bracket you could install almost any crank, so **all you need is a BB30 to GXP bottom bracket**.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right ! ... now the doubt that I have is if the bottom bracket Ceramicspeed BB30 SRAM GXP will work in my bike with my crank length ... that its the only doubt that I have before buy it !

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer would be to have bought the BB30 option (30mm spindle) and switched to a standard BB30 bottom bracket.

Presumably you have a 24mm spindle version. If you can return it, swap it for the BB30 version and change out the BB bearings.

Comment: Got flagged by someone - can you expand on why this helps?   Too many BB standards!

Comment: In the photos, you can see that he has a BB30 to Shimano 24mm bottom bracket adapter. That means that his frame can fit a standard BB30 bottom bracket, which would be compatible with the BB30 quarq with a new bottom bracket without any adaptor.